# Is the "of" in the following sentence mandatory, old-fashioned or ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar

Is the "of" in the following sentence mandatory, old-fashioned or ungrammatical?

> I am quite "of" a beginner.

In my research, I saw that in many cases the "of" tends to be dropped. For example: "many years" is preferred to the old-fashioned "many a year".

Comment: There is usually no such thing as "ungrammatical". The word should be *abnormal*, *unusual* or *nonstandard grammar*. Otherwise, "accepted", "normal", "formal". The reason being, even pidgin English is grammatical, if the regional pidgin has a consistent pattern - because grammar = pattern of usage.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Linguists say that things are non-grammatical all the time. Such statements have to be made in regards to specific dialects, but they're still accurate. Non-standard is more about minority dialects/varieties.

Comment: Please cite the source of the quoted sentence. Also, show as much of the context as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *quite* has mutated over the years from describing an extremity to describing an indistinct attribute. Therefore, the word *quite* could mean

- extremely
- very
- truly
- nearly
- somewhat

Therefore all you have to do is to replace *quite* with one of those words, and see if the sentence sounds acceptable to you.

- He is quite handsome. He is very handsome.
- He is quite the beginner. He is nearly the beginner.
- He is quite a beginner. He is nearly a beginner. He is somewhat a beginner.
- He is not quite there yet. He is not nearly there yet.

Therefore, use the phrase with your full rejoicing heart ...

- He is quite a beginner.

[quite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quite)  (kwīt)

adv.

1. To the greatest extent; completely: quite alone; not quite finished. See Usage Note at perfect.
2. Actually; really: I'm quite positive about it.
3. To a degree; rather: quite soon; quite tasty.

[Middle English, from quite, clear, free, from Old French, from Latin quiētus, freed; see quiet.]

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is ungrammatical because *quite* is used to describe the extent of something.

With *of*, the sentence essentially says *beginner* is of the amount *quite*, which makes no sense. We need a real quantity.

If you change *quite* to *a bit*, you now have a quantity that will fit in our analysis above. *Beginner* is now of the quantity *a bit*.

> I am a bit of a beginner.

So to give you a straight answer, *of* in this context is attributing *quite* to *a beginner*.

Comment: Thank you very much. This doubt has been nagging me for a long time.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quite says you have not had quite the exposure to the word, quite sufficiently to provide quite such an opinion.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I quite thank you for your comment, but I stand by my answer still because I said _quite_ is ungrammatical when followed by _of_, not by itself.